# What component do I need (power)

Tags: power

I want to power my board using a 9v battery. I also want to power a component in my circuit from the same power source (9v battery) but ONLY when my board sends a signal (say from D1 pin).

What component allows me to restrict power this way? I don't want to activate the component through signal, but actually power it after the signal is sent.

Comment: A P-channel MOSFET driven by an N-channel MOSFET in the 9V connection? An N-channel MOSFET in the ground signal? A relay in either signal? There's lots of ways of achieving it - the best depends on what the "component" is you're controlling.

Comment: Having done further research and changing my search terms, it seems I can use a transistor as an electrical switch. I these methods and update with progress.

Comment: Are you using a 9V block battery? I hope not, because these are really only for low power applications. Otherwise you will drain it very fast and it might not be able to peovide enough current, depending on your components

Comment: Transistor was the component I was looking for, NPN. It is a 9v block battery, the circuit is only powered for minutes at a time, I'm only testing circuitry rather than running a finished product for the time being

Comment: You should use a MOSFET transistor, not a conventional transistor. Those have significant ON resistance, and waste a fair amount of power as heat. MOSEFETs have capacitive inputs and very low ON resistance, so are a better choice for efficiently switching power, particularly in battery-powered applications where you have to limit your average mA of power consumption. You'd also be better off using a switching regulator, as the built-in regulator in an Arduino is a linear regulator, which wastes any excess voltage as heat.